# I want to get the printed output in a list like [output, output]

Tags: python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is the code of my script, I want the output to be returned in a list rather than what is in the out put now (shown below)

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    webpage = requests.get("https://www.spinneyslebanon.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pepsi")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find_all('a', 'product-item-link')
    price = soup.find_all('span', class_='price')

    for index, tp in enumerate(zip(title, price)):
        if index >= 10:
            break
        t, p = tp
        print("{:<60} {:<30}".format(t.get_text(strip=True),
                                     p.get_text(strip=True)))
```

this is the output:

```
   Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml                                      LBP 17,999                    
   Pepsi Regular Bottle 330ml                                   LBP 3,999                     
   Pepsi Black Regular Bottle 330ml                             LBP 3,999                     
   Pepsi Diet Bottle 2.25L                                      LBP 10,999                    
   Pepsi Regular 2.25L                                          LBP 10,999                    
   Pepsi Regular Can 185ml                                      LBP 4,999                     
   Pepsi Diet Bottle 1.25L                                      LBP 8,999                     
   Pepsi Diet Can 185ml                                         LBP 4,999                     
   Pepsi Regular Bottle 1.25L                                   LBP 8,999                     
   Pepsi Diet Pet - 330Ml                                       LBP 3,999
```

I want it to be [Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml, Pepsi Regular Bottle 330ml,Pepsi Black Regular Bottle 330ml....]

same for the price [LBP 17,999, LBP 3,999, LBP 3,999....]

Comment: to the `OP`, You don't need to edit your question where you clear it and even you tried to edit the answer which you received with the word `lol`. Please respect the people taken time to read your question and provide an answer. on the other side if you are afraid your boss or something else so why you came here? to just post a question and then receive an answer and then delete it and run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = requests.get(
    "https://www.spinneyslebanon.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pepsi"
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.find_all("a", "product-item-link")
price = soup.find_all("span", class_="price")

titles = []
prices = []
for index, tp in enumerate(zip(title, price)):
    if index >= 10:
        break
    titles.append(tp[0].get_text(strip=True))
    prices.append(tp[1].get_text(strip=True))

print(titles)
print(prices)
```

Creates two lists `titles` and `prices` and prints them:

```py
['Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml', 'Pepsi Regular Bottle 330ml', 'Pepsi Black Regular Bottle 330ml', 'Pepsi Diet Bottle 2.25L', 'Pepsi Regular 2.25L', 'Pepsi Regular Can 185ml', 'Pepsi Diet Bottle 1.25L', 'Pepsi Diet Can 185ml', 'Pepsi Regular Bottle 1.25L', 'Pepsi Diet Pet - 330Ml']
['LBP 17,999', 'LBP 3,999', 'LBP 3,999', 'LBP 10,999', 'LBP 10,999', 'LBP 4,999', 'LBP 8,999', 'LBP 4,999', 'LBP 8,999', 'LBP 3,999']
```